# Process a ppt file and show it as a image or SWF in flex. Help required

Tags: apache-flex, powerpoint

Here is my requirement. I have a flex application where the user upload or a PPT file and i have to present it to 'n' clients in the same flex application.

My options where,

1. Convert PPT to images corresponding to the slides. (Is this feasible via APIs')
2. Convert PPT to PDF and load in in a flex application.
3. Convert PPT to swf and load it in a flex application. (Any options?)
4. Or any other suggestions>?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Convert PPT to images corresponding to the slides. (Is this
> ```
>
> feasible via APIs')

Powerpoint has an option to save each slide as an image.  This would not be possible using any existing Flex/Actionript APIs that I'm aware of.  I suppose, in theory, you could write something in ActionScript to parse the PPT format and extra slides as images.  I would not expect it to be trivial, though.

> Convert PPT to PDF and load in in a flex application.

There is no way to load a PDF inside a browser based Flex application.  You can do so inside an AIR app, though.  How did you plan to do the conversion?  On a server?

> Convert PPT to swf and load it in a flex application. (Any options?)

I believe Adobe has a tool; called [Presenter](http://www.adobe.com/products/presenter/) which you can use to turn a Powerpoint into a SWF.  However, that is not an API based tool.

> ```
> Or any other suggestions>?
> ```

Upload the Powerpoint to the server and do the conversions on the server.  [Apache's POI project](http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/index.html) is one way to access PPT files from Java.  I do not know the extent of it's integration.  ColdFusion has a [cfpresentation](http://cfquickdocs.com/cf9/?getDoc=CFPRESENTATION#CFPRESENTATION) tag, which will convert a PPT to an HTML presentation; which you could then display over the Flex app using an iFrame.  Or, assuming it uses images for each slide; you could display the images individually in your Flex app.

Answer (score 0):

Can flex do COM automation and can you assume that PowerPoint will be present on the PC where you'll do the conversion?  If so, exporting slides as images is fairly simple.

The PowerPoint Application object has a Presentations collection with a member representing each currently open presentation.  Each Presentation object (ie, each member of the Presentations collection) has a Slides collection. You can call the .Export method on each Slide object to export the slide to a format of your choice at whatever resolution you wish (up to 3072 pixels max, and sometimes very low rez exports look like the cat used them for a claw-toy)